# How does one convert string to number in JDOQL?

Tags: jdo, datanucleus, jdoql

I have a JDOQL/DataNucleus storage layer which stores values that can have multiple primitive types in a varchar field. Some of them are numeric, and I need to compare (</>/...) them with numeric constants. How does one achieve that? I was trying to use e.g. (java.lang.)Long.parse on the field or value (e.g. java.lang.Long.parseLong(field) > java.lang.Long.parseLong(string_param)), supplying a parameter of type long against string field, etc. but it doesn't work. In fact, I very rarely get any errors, for various combinations it would return all values or no values for no easily discernible reasons.
Is there documentation for this?

Clarification: the field is of string type (actually a string collection from which I do a get). For some subset of values they may store ints, e.g. "3" string, and I need to do e.g. value >= 2 filters.
I tried using casts, but not much, they do produce errors, let me investigate some more

Comment: Since we are talking JDO here, the fields you want to compare numerically, are actually `String`s ? I mean the persisted class member variable that you need to numerically compare to, is a `String` ?

Answer (score 0):

JDO has a well documented set of methods that are valid for use with JDOQL, upon which DataNucleus JDO adds some additional ones and allows users to add on support for others as per 
http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_3/jdo/jdoql.html#methods

then you also can use JDOQL casts (on the same page as that link).

Comment: The casts do not work for this scenario; with filter like "(Long)values.get(2) > param0" I get 
JDOUserException: Cannot perform operation "cast to org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.sql.expression.StringLiteral@21789983" on org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.sql.expression.StringExpression@74a6789f
Looking at SQLExpression source, to what I cast does not matter, StringExpression cannot be cast to anything.
To implement "first-class" support for SQL92 and non-SQL stores, what does one need to do, implement both SQL and in-memory plugin with method such as toLong? Would DN use each one where appropriate?

Comment: Just because cast hasn't been implemented doesn't mean someone couldn't contribute the ability to cast a String to something (let's face it, most people store 'strings' as 'strings', so if you want that supported you have to contribute it). To do it as a method call, you implement whichever one you'll be using ... if evaluating it in datastore do the sql_method, and if in-memory then store_query_methods (or you provide both if you may need both at some point)